# How to protect rspec_api_documentation apitome route without a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have a set of API documentation pages that I want to password protect using devise. The docs are generated using rspec_api_documentation. The gem uses rspec to execute the API methods and create html or json doc files. I'm generating json and using another gem, apitome, as a viewer.

This is all working beautifully and my api docs can be found at /api/docs, but I can't figure out how to require authentication to view the docs.

The docs are viewed through apitome so it using rails. There isn't a route in routes.rb, but the apitom initializer mounts the docs.

From apitom initializer:

```
# This determines where the Apitome routes will be mounted. Changing this to "/api/documentation" for instance would
# allow you to browse to http://localhost:3000/api/documentation to see your api documentation. Set to nil and mount
# it yourself if you need to.
config.mount_at = "/api/docs"
```

https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation

https://github.com/modeset/apitome

I found this How-to that is supposed to make every page on the site require authenication, but I'm still able to hit the docs url without signing in.

```
#https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-authentication-for-all-pages
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You can take control of Apitome controller and request auhentication.

- configure apitome to not mount itself by setting mount_at to nil
- write your controller ApidocsController extending Apitome::DocsController
- add   before_filter :authenticate_user! in your controller
- add a route to your controller: get '/api/docs', to: 'apidocs#index'

Controller implementatin would go like this:

```
class ApidocsController < Apitome::DocsController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Comment: Hmm, something's not working so well... The "simulated response" URI generated in the document page is in `/simulate/*path`, whereas I would like them to be `/api/docs/simulate/...`.
Not sure there is a solution to that...

Comment: This is a documented problem. Check this apitome issue together with the proposed solutions: https://github.com/modeset/apitome/issues/36

Comment: Thank you @jogaco, you'll notice I'm the last person to comment on that GitHub thread, explaining why this still is a problem. :)

Comment: In order for this to work I had to add ```mount Apitome::Engine => 'apidocs#index'``` to the bottom of  ```config/routes.rb```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Devise already configured (for example if you already use ActiveAdmin) you can share the same authenticated session.

You have to disable the default mounting of Apitome:

```
# config/initializers/apitome.rb
Apitome.setup do |config|
  config.mount_at = nil
  # ...
end
```

Since this will break links in Apitome, you have to add to your application.rb:

```
# config/application.rb
# ...
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.after_initialize do
    Apitome.configuration.mount_at = '/docs'
  end 
  # ...
end
```

Then force mount of the Apitome engine under Devise authenticated session:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  authenticated :admin_user do
    mount Apitome::Engine => '/docs'
  end
  # root_to ...
end
```

Now /docs is accessible only for already authenticated users.

PS: replace :admin_user (default for Active Admin) to :user or any other model name where Devise is configured.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the cut down rails api, so did not have any views or devise and so no simple way to implement password protection.  Accordingly I went for the following solution.

```
Apitome.setup do |config|
  config.mount_at = nil
  # ...
end
```

and in the routes.rb file:

```
mount Apitome::Engine => '/api/docs' unless Rails.env.production?
```

Finally, I just did a pdf of the api/docs page, and then sent the pdf to anyone what had a right to see the documentation.  Obviously not suitable for a large user base, but works fine for a small one, e.g. within a company's IT group.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using Raddocs, add mounted route inside authentication block as below:

```
  authenticate :user do
    mount Raddocs::App => "/docs"
  end
```